# SvelteKit Dev Server + Auth.js - Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden on sign in

Tags: javascript, cors, google-oauth, sveltekit, next-auth

I am using Auth.js for authentication in SvelteKit. I followed the instructions given by the documentation [here](https://authjs.dev/reference/sveltekit/modules/main), but when I tried to click my sign in button nothing happens and in the console I get a 403 error from `/auth/signin/google?`  and `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'C', "Cross-site"... is not valid JSON`, meaning that the POST request is returning an error of "Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden". I followed the exact instructions as in the documentation, but using the google provider instead.

```
// /src/hooks.server.ts
import { SvelteKitAuth } from "@auth/sveltekit"
import Google from "@auth/core/providers/google"
import { GOOGLE_ID, GOOGLE_SECRET } from "$env/static/private"

export const handle = SvelteKitAuth({
    //@ts-expect-error issue https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6174
    providers: [Google({
        clientId: GOOGLE_ID,
        clientSecret: GOOGLE_SECRET,
    })]
});
```

```
// /src/routes/+layout.server.ts
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async (event) => {
  return {
    session: await event.locals.getSession()
  };
};
```

```html
<!-- /src/routes/+layout.svelte -->
<script>
    import '../app.postcss';
    
  import { DarkMode } from 'flowbite-svelte';
    import { Navbar, NavBrand, NavLi, NavUl, NavHamburger, Button, Input, P } from 'flowbite-svelte';
    import { page } from "$app/stores";
    import { signIn, signOut } from "@auth/sveltekit/client"
</script>

<div>
    <Navbar let:hidden let:toggle>
  <NavBrand href="/">
    <img
      src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg"
      class="mr-3 h-6 sm:h-9"
      alt="Flowbite Logo"
    />
    <span class="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white">
      AMC Trainer
    </span>
  </NavBrand>
  <div class="flex md:order-2">
        <DarkMode class="mr-3" />
        {#if $page.data.session}
            <P>Signed in as {$page.data.session.user?.name}</P>
        {:else}
<!--            <Button size="sm" href="/auth/signin" data-sveltekit-preload-data="off">Sign in</Button>     -->
            <Button size="sm" on:click={() => {signIn("google", {callbackUrl: "https://amc.grapecoder.repl.co/"})}}>Sign in</Button>
        {/if}
    <NavHamburger on:click={toggle} />
  </div>
  <NavUl {hidden} class="order-1">
    <NavLi href="/" active={$page.url.pathname == "/"}>Home</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/about">About</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/services">Services</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/pricing">Pricing</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/contact">Contact</NavLi>
  </NavUl>
</Navbar>
<!--text-slate-900 dark:text-slate-100  -->
<div class="my-5 lg:mx-40 md:mx-20 mx-10 ">
    <slot />
</div>

</div>
```

[Here is my GitHub repo.](https://github.com/megagames-me/amc-trainer)

I tried to add the "callbackUrl" property to the sign in button. I wasn't sure what was wrong with my code, though. I also went through the type definitions for the provider to see if there was anything I could add as an option to fix this. Expected behaviour would be that I get sent to the Google accounts sign in page and be able to log in normally.

Comment: Did you try with GitHub client id and secret?   What makes you think it will work with Google?

Comment: Because I'm using the proper google provider. It is meant to work like this.

Comment: Tbh issues with third party library really should be taken up on the issue forum for the library they are the best people to help you.  you may even find the help is already there https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/6589

Comment: It's not a third party library as the provider is provided by Auth.js themselves. Anyway, I already solved the issue, which is documented here https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6451

Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Its not provided by Google or in their documtation making it third party.

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. The issue here was with Auth.js itself so it doesn't really matter here.